# Active State Machine able to modify UI elements

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, state-machine

Hello community I was wondering if I could obtain some software architecture advice on the following. In an upcoming project I have the requirement of programming an active state machine running at 100 ms which checks on the content of a data model and fires off the appropriate triggers to switch from one state to another. Upon entering and exiting each state, I have to enable and disable certain UI elements.

My question, what approach can I take as to not tightly couple the UI modifications from the state machine? Currently I have an active state machine which has references to the UI elements and from each state transition I can enable/disable UI elements. But I feel this isn't clean and would like to know a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought here is you can have your state machine set up some events that fire when you enter/exit states. You can have the events pass what the new/old state is if you want. Have the UI code subscribe to these and change the UI when they fire.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I will look into your suggestion and get back to you in a couple of days. Once again, I greatly appreciate your comment.